# c++: logger class without globals or singletons or passing it to every method

Tags: c++, logging, dependency-injection, singleton

Does anyone knows if it's possible to have a class like a logger without :

- using a singleton or a global (a la std::cout)
- passing an instance/pointer/reference to every method which needs it

I take the example of a logger class, but I have a few classes in my application which would benefit from this (for example, the undo manager).

There are several issues with every solution :

- using a singleton is problematic for testing (along with the many reasons it's generaly not a good idea to use one) . It's the same with a global. Furthermore, nothing guarantees there will be only ONE instance in the application, and it's not even a requirement (why not have 2 loggers for example ?)
- passing it to every object constructor (dependency injection), leads to a lot of boilerplate code, and can be error prone because you have to copy/paste the same code a lot of times. Can one seriously consider having a pointer to a Logger in every single class' constructor ???????

So I was wondering if there is a third alternative, in C++, I never heard of ? 
To me it sounds like it would require some black magic under the hood, but I've been pleasantly surprised by some techniques I learned in stack overflow that I couldn't find in google, so I know there are some real gurus here ;)

Surprisingly, I found many discussions about how to design singletons, or why should one not use singletons, but I couldn't find a post addressing my issue...

Comment: I've seen a logging class that would simply open the log file every time a statement was written to the log and log name was hardcoded (and optionally passed in if you wanted to write to a different file). No globals, singletons or passing objects to every method, but not exactly the black magic solution that you are looking for.  In fact I'm still working on removing that log class from the product :)

Comment: if the logger class exists then is it ok for you to go and edit every method ? If so, then I can suggest something.

Comment: @iammilind : Do you mean every method of the logger class ? Yes it's possible, I'm impatient to hear your suggestion :)
@DXM : :))))

Comment: sorry I might have misunderstood your question. I thought you want to log all the functions which are getting called throughout your codeflow. After seeing below answer, it seems that you want something different. Or may be I still haven't understood well, what exactly is your question. :)

Comment: Take a look at [Hypodermic](http://code.google.com/p/hypodermic/). Looks not very beautifully, but I think it may be a solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would imagine you could do something similar to what is done in Java with the Log4j package (and is probably done with the Log4c version of it):

Have a static method which can return multiple logger instances:

```
Logger someLogger = Logger.getLogger("logger.name");
```

The `getLogger()` method isn't returning a singleton object.  It's returning the named logger (creating it if necessary).  `Logger` is just an interface (in C++ it could be a totally abstract class) -- the caller doesn't need to know the actual types of the `Logger` objects being created.

You could continue to mimic Log4j and have an overload of `getLogger()` that also takes a factory object:

```
Logger someLogger = Logger.getLogger("logger.name", factory);
```

That call would use `factory` to build the logger instance, giving you more control over what underlying `Logger` objects were being created, likely helping your mocking.

So there's no need to pass anything into the constructors, methods, etc. of your own code.  You just grab the desired named `Logger` when you need it and log to it.  Depending on the thread safety of the logging code you write, you could have what `getLogger()` returns be a static member of your class so you'd only have to call `getLogger()` once per class.

Comment: Sounds sensible, however, if you use the factory, you still have to pass the factory to your class constructor, don't you ?

Comment: No, you don't.  If the factory's build method is such that `factory` can be a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object), you can just create an instance of the factory object on the fly in the code that calls `getLogger()`.

Comment: I really don't see the benefit of this over a singleton.  If they all have to wrap some error log file handle, then that file handle is already a singleton.  Wrapping it with a single one-member-field struct or simple singleton class with just the file pointer member and no virtual methods equates to just the singleton file handle object anyway.

I don't like singletons either, but this doesn't sound advantageous, as a way around them.  It's essentially getSingletonSuitableFor(someParam).

Comment: user1024732: In multi-threaded programming, writing to a log file requires synchronization. Creation of multiple log files (one file per OS thread) is allowed in some projects and disallowed in others. In multiple concurrent transaction handling, each log message must be prefixed with the transaction ID, therefore there must be some intermediate logging helper objects that is told what the current transaction ID it is processing, and modifies the log message string accordingly. In general the bigger the software is, the less it can yield to novice concerns.

Answer (score 7):

How about a class with some static methods?

```
class Logger
{
public:
  static void record(string message)
  {
    static ofstream fout("log");
    fout << message << endl;;
  }
  ...
};

...

void someOtherFunctionSomewhere()
{
  Logger::record("some string");
  ...
}
```

No Singleton, no global variable, but any code that can see `Logger.h` can call the member function, and if all of the public member functions return `void`, it's trivially easy to stub out for testing.

Comment: That's great, it works well with the logger but what about classes which need a state ? The undo manager for example keeps an history of user action and therefore, needs to keep track of what's happening.

Comment: @Dinaiz: No problem. Make `record` a template, define `operator<<` for your state class, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good alternative in C++, however there is one in Emacs Lisp that might be worth to think about: [dynamic binding of variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Binding.html#Dynamic-Binding). The basic concept goes like this, when you refer to a variable, you will access not necessarily the global variable by the name, but the one last defined in the path of execution by the same name. In pseudo-C++ code this would look like this:

```
// Pseudo-C++ with dynamic binding
Logger logger = Logger("GlobalLogger");

void foo() { logger.log("message"); }

int main() 
{
   foo(); // first
   {
      Logger logger = Logger("MyLogger");
      foo(); // second
   }
   foo(); // third
}
```

In this pseudo-C++ example when you call `foo()` the first time, GlobalLogger would be used, when you call it a second time, MyLogger would be called instead, as the MyLogger would override the global variable for as long as it is in scope, even inside `foo()`. The third call would go back to GlobalLogger as MyLogger dropped out of scope. This allows overriding the global logger with a custom one for selected pieces of code without having to pass a logger object through all the code and without having to set a global variable.

Real C++ doesn't have dynamic binding, but it should be possible to replicate aspects of it:

```
std::stack<Logger> logger = { Logger("GlobalLogger") };

void foo() { logger.top().log("message"); }

int main()
{
    foo();
    {
      logger.push(Logger("MyLogger"));
      foo();
      logger.pop();
    }
    foo();
}
```

For further cleanup the stack should be hidden inside a `DynamicBinding` class, the manual .push()/.pop() operations could be hidden behind a scoped guard and there will be issues with multithreading that will need to be taken care of. But the basic concept might work and give more flexibility then a simple singleton or global variable.